# cin.ignore(3) after failure to get a double with cin >> var

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ with c++ Primer Plus, and I'm on chapter 7 and trying to create the following function:

```
double getDouble(const char * message){
    double temp;
    std::cout << (message);
    if (!(std::cin >> temp)){
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(3); // Why does this work specifically?
        std::cout << "Input not double!" << std::endl;
        return 0.0;
    }
    return temp;
```

}

Comment: C++ Primer Plus isn't so good book. C++ Primer (by Lippman) is better.

Comment: So far I find this book very very helpful. Since I already have programming backgrounds (nothing to do with pointers, though. That concept is still quite alienating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ standard guarantees (§27.6.1.3/23 in the '03 standard) that passing `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` will ignore everything in the stream until the specified delimiter or end of input is reached. So change

```
std::cin.ignore(3);
```

to

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
```

Using magic numbers such as `3` when calling `ignore` is very rarely appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

`istream::ignore` well, ignores the next N characters or until the delimiter is hit. The `3` seems like a random magic number to me. Or what did you want to know?

Comment: @ultimate: Well, maybe the author thought it would be enough. It works for input like "d23 32", but "d23 32b" would be too long and the "b" would linger in the buffer.